# NoClassDefFoundError when adding Universal Tween Engine via gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I've been doing a little game development experimentation with Kilobolt's flappy bird clone tutorial in Android Studio. I was able to pretty easily setup the project with a Libgdx project generator (http://www.todroid.com/android-gdx-game-creation-part-i-setting-up-up-android-studio-for-creating-games/), but at one point in the tutorial you are required to add the Univeral Tween Engine library to the project.

This is where I get stuck, because I'm adding the dependency through gradle

`compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar'`

but I always get a NoClassDefFoundError for the Tween class, even though it compiles.

Perhaps someone knows how to add this library correctly to Android Studio in the context of a cross-platform LibGdx project? The other posting answers were related to Eclipse, or they referenced menu options that are not available in this project setup, like Add Library.

Comment: have you solved this. Am also getting same error. Please answer if you have solved this

Comment: No, sorry it kind of fell off my radar. I'll give it a try again today at some point and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: It is solved when I just followed this link https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine